# $\aleph_0+\aleph_0=\aleph_0$? or $2\aleph_0$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The problem is 'In a finite group, show that the number of nonidentity elements that satisfy the equation $x^5=e$ is a multiple of 4.'. I did it and got answer that cause $x$, $x^2$, $x^3$, $x^4$ always come together but when the condition that group be finite is omitted, what can I say the number of nonidentity elements that satisfy the equation? I first thought it would be $\aleph_0+\aleph_0+\aleph_0+\aleph_0$. But $\aleph_0+\aleph_0=\aleph_0$? or $2\aleph_0$? This algebra problem makes me solve set theory problem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The question you're asking (what's up with $\aleph_0+\aleph_0$?) and the problem you're working on (what's the number of elements in an infinite group fulfilling a certain requirement?) are not really related at all. Which one of them are you actually interested in?

Comment: It's both: $\aleph_0+\aleph_0=\aleph_0$ and $\aleph_0+\aleph_0=2\aleph_0$, what you do not realize is that $\aleph_0=2\aleph_0$.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to ask, in a rather unclear way, whether "the number" of elements in an **infinite group** which fulfill the equation $\;x^5=1\;$ is (at most) $\;\aleph_0\;$ , since in the finite group case we have....etc. Now read the whole question!

Comment: Thanks everyone. I got answer from third comment. And no other question. That's all. When the group is finite of infinite case.

Comment: @지나가던유저 How exactly "$\aleph_0=2\aleph_0$" answers your question about the number of solutions to $x^5=e$ in the infinite case? The answer "$\aleph_0$" is just wrong.

Comment: @freakish, unfortunately, OP saying: "I got answer from third comment. And no other question." makes it a duplicate.

Comment: @Ennar no, it doesn't. Because this is [a XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). OP **believes** that the cardinal arithmetic solves his original problem while it doesn't. And the third comment (while correct) is misleading him even more.

Comment: @freakish, I'd say you pointed that out clearly to OP, but it's their responsibility to recognize their mistake and actually read the answers they received.

Answer (score 5):

As you've noted if $g^5=e$ for some $g\in G$ then $x^5=e$ for any $x\in R_g=\{g,g^2,g^3,g^4\}$ and these sets are either equal or disjoint, and $|R_g|=4$ if $g\neq e$. And so if $k$ is the number of nontrivial solutions to $x^5=e$ and $k<\infty$ then indeed $4$ divides $k$. Note that I didn't assume that $G$ is finite, only that $k$ is. Also note that this can be generalized to any prime number: for any prime $p$ the number of (nontrivial) solutions to $x^p=e$ is divisible by $p-1$ if finite. For non-primes this doesn't hold since different $R_g$ sets need not be disjoint (and so they don't partition all solutions) and need not be of equal size.

Now if $\mathcal{K}$ is any infinite cardinal number then I will show that there is a group $G$ having exactly $\mathcal{K}$ solutions to $x^5=e$, assuming the Axiom of Choice. And so your conclusion "there is $\aleph_0+\aleph_0+\aleph_0+\aleph_0$ solutions" is incorrect (even though $\aleph_0=2\aleph_0$ which is not really relevant).

Let $G$ be the infinite direct sum $\bigoplus_{\mathcal{K}}\mathbb{Z}_5$, which has exactly $\mathcal{K}$ elements by the AoC. And so $G$ has at most $\mathcal{K}$ solutions to $x^5=e$.

On the other hand $G$ has at least $\mathcal{K}$ solutions to $x^5=e$, namely for a fixed $i\in \mathcal{K}$ (here I treat $\mathcal{K}$ as a set of size $\mathcal{K}$) we have

$$f_i:\mathcal{K}\to\mathbb{Z}_5$$
$$f_i(x)=\begin{cases}1 &\text{if }x=i \\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

which is a solution and $f_i=f_j$ if and only if $i=j$. And so there are at least $\mathcal{K}$ solutions to $x^5=e$.

All in all $G$ has exactly $\mathcal{K}$ solutions to $x^5=e$.

Finally note that an infinite group $G$ can have any (valid) finite number of solutions to $x^5=e$ as well. For example if $G$ is finite with $k<\infty$ solutions then $G\times\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite with $k$ solutions.

**//Edit:** As @bof noticed the Axiom of Choice is not needed for $2^{\aleph_0}$ case since the group of rotations of a two-dimensional sphere has $2^{\aleph_0}$ elements of order $5$ (or any other order $\geq 2$). These are rotations around different lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$ going through the origin.

Comment: For $K=2^{\aleph_0}$ a very concrete example, without the Axiom of Choice, is the group of rotations of the sphere.

Comment: Please avoid overediting. Take your time with each edit. If you need a sandbox, please use https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-posts to test and revise before making the final edits here.

Comment: @bof could you explain a bit more? Im not sure I get it.

Comment: I know nothing at all about rotation groups. All I know is that the rotations of the sphere form a group, and a rotation of $2\pi/5$ radians about any axis will have order $5$.

Comment: Beats me. I was thinking of the ordinary $2$-dimensional sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ in $\mathbb R^3$. The axis of rotation can be any line through the origin, and there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ of those.

Comment: @bof ahh, of course, you can rotate around any line. Yes, you are right. I really have to learn rotations some day.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct, because $\aleph_0 = 2\aleph_0$

For example, $|\mathbb{N}|=\aleph_0$ and $|\mathbb{Z}| = \aleph_0$ as well. I think this illustrates why that is true.

Answer (score 1):

Function $f\colon\mathbb N\sqcup \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ defined by $f(n,i) = 2n + i$ is a bijection and thus $\aleph_0+\aleph_0 = |\mathbb N\sqcup \mathbb N| = |\mathbb N| = \aleph_0.$

Comment: Sure, downvote. Also, vote to delete. This still is an answer to the question asked as it is in the current form. Sad thing is that the person who downvoted not just my answer, but others as well, will probably not even be here to follow what changes. Please prove me wrong. I am here, following all the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

By Hessenberg theorem $\kappa\cdot\kappa=\kappa$, for $\kappa$ infinite cardinal
This implies $\kappa\leq 2\kappa=\kappa+\kappa\leq \kappa\cdot\kappa=\kappa$. So, $\kappa=2\kappa=\kappa+\kappa=\kappa\cdot\kappa$

So in particular $\aleph_0=\aleph_0+\aleph_0=2\aleph_0$. So I guess the answer to your question is both.